# WPF Multitrigger.ExitActions will override normal Trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a problem which im not able to solve, so im asking here to get some help.

This is a part of code which is causing me problem:

```
<Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation To="#E1E1E1"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TabItem.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                         Duration="00:00:00.3"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
            <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation To="#F2F2F2"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TabItem.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                         Duration="00:00:00.3"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3090C7" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#F2F2F2" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

What I want to do is when i mouseover an tabitem (which is NOT selected) the background fade to darker gray and when mouse leaves the dark gray color should fade back to lighter one. This is working fine (using multitriggers as u can see), but the problem is when i click tab item (not selected one) the tabitem will change to isSelected trigger style for like 0.1 second and then Multitrigger.ExitActions will override the style and tabitem will turn to dark gray color.

Im not native english speaker! I tried to desribe my problem as good as i can. Thanks to everyone who will try to help me out.

Comment: Storyboard is Animation. Animation have higher priority. To solve this  you should also use ColorAnimation in IsSelected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `ColorAnimation` within your `ExitActions` storyboard, remove the `To` value. This means that the animation will take place, but the target value will be the currently set one - in this case the one acquired by the style change of the `IsSelected` trigger. Your code should look like this:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation To="#E1E1E1"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TabItem.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                    Duration="00:00:00.3"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
        <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TabItem.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                    Duration="00:00:00.3"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
    </MultiTrigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3090C7" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#F2F2F2" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

I didn't actually check if this code is 100% correct. If it does not work, please feel free to inform me about it. If you want more information on value precedence of dependency properties, please read this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx